# How can I write self-modifying code that runs efficiently on modern x64 processors?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, intel, dispatch, self-modifying

I'm trying to speed up a variable-bitwidth integer compression scheme and I'm interested in generating and executing assembly code on-the-fly.   Currently a lot of time is spent on mispredicted indirect branches, and generating code based on the series of bitwidths as found seems to be the only way avoid this penalty.

The general technique is referred to as "subroutine threading" (or "call threading", although this has other definitions as well).  The goal is to take advantage of the processors efficient call/ret prediction so as to avoid stalls.  The approach is well described here:
[http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~amaral/cascon/CDP05/slides/CDP05-berndl.pdf](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Eamaral/cascon/CDP05/slides/CDP05-berndl.pdf)

The generated code will be simply a series of calls followed by a return.  If there were 5 'chunks' of widths [4,8,8,4,16], it would look like:

```
call $decode_4
call $decode_8
call $decode_8
call $decode_4
call $decode_16
ret
```

In actual use, it will be a longer series of calls, with a sufficient length that each series will likely be unique and only called once.  Generating and calling the code is well documented, both here and elsewhere.  But I haven't found much discussion of efficiency beyond a simple "don't do it" or a well-considered "there be dragons".  Even the [Intel documentation](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf) speaks mostly in generalities:

> 8.1.3 Handling Self- and Cross-Modifying Code
>
> The act of a processor writing data into a currently executing code
> segment with the intent of executing that data as code is called
> self-modifying code. IA-32 processors exhibit model-specific behavior
> when executing self modified code, depending upon how far ahead of the
> current execution pointer the code has been modified.  ...
> Self-modifying code will execute at a lower level of performance than
> non-self-modifying or normal code. The degree of the performance
> deterioration will depend upon the frequency of modification and
> specific characteristics of the code.
>
> 11.6 SELF-MODIFYING CODE
>
> A write to a memory location in a code segment that is currently
> cached in the processor causes the associated cache line (or lines) to
> be invalidated. This check is based on the physical address of the
> instruction. In addition, the P6 family and Pentium processors check
> whether a write to a code segment may modify an instruction that has
> been prefetched for execution. If the write affects a prefetched
> instruction, the prefetch queue is invalidated. This latter check is
> based on the linear address of the instruction. For the Pentium 4 and
> Intel Xeon processors, a write or a snoop of an instruction in a code
> segment, where the target instruction is already decoded and resident
> in the trace cache, invalidates the entire trace cache. The latter
> behavior means that programs that self-modify code can cause severe
> degradation of performance when run on the Pentium 4 and Intel Xeon
> processors.

While there is a performance counter to determine whether bad things are happening (C3 04 MACHINE_CLEARS.SMC: *Number of self-modifying-code machine clears detected*) I'd like to know more specifics, particularly for Haswell.  My impression is that as long as I can write the generated code far enough ahead of time that the instruction prefetch has not gotten there yet, and as long as I don't trigger the SMC detector by modifying code on the same page (quarter-page?) as anything currently being executed, then I should get good performance.  But all the details seem extremely vague: how close is too close?  How far is far enough?

Trying to make these into specific questions:

1. What is the maximum distance ahead of the current instruction that
   the Haswell prefetcher ever runs?
2. What is the maximum distance behind the current instruction that the
   Haswell 'trace cache' might contain?
3. What is the actual penalty in cycles for a MACHINE_CLEARS.SMC event
   on Haswell?
4. How can I run the generate/execute cycle in a predicted loop while
   preventing the prefetcher from eating its own tail?
5. How can I arrange the flow so that each piece of generated code is
   always "seen for the first time" and not stepping on instructions
   already cached?

Comment: Interesting questions indeed, but I get the impression that most of the points you list are research questions, i.e. I suspect the way to find out is to do the proper experiment.

Comment: Experimentation is likely the best way indeed.  Self-modifying code is considered evil and a design defect these days.  Occasionally it may be necessary, but there's just not going to be much info available as people avoid it...

Comment: Experimentation will definitely be necessary, but given the recent advances with JIT compilation of dynamic languages, I was hoping that there were some better guidelines.  The big difference though is that the JIT is usually only done once and is unmodified thereafter.

Comment: JIT doesn't have to be done once, you can have multiple levels of optimization based on the level of code profiling you reach.

Comment: 2. The uop cache in SnB-family (including Haswell) is NOT a trace cache.  Each way (group of up to 6 uops, what Agner Fog calls a line) knows the address-range of x86 instructions it's caching.  Unconditional jumps (like JMP) do end a way/line, but uops in a way have to be statically contiguous.

Comment: The threading achieved by using direct CALLs instead of indirect jumps / calls might be a bigger deal for P4 than for CPUs without a trace cache (i.e. everything else).  Although it is interesting to note that the slides you linked show speedups on PPC, but modern Intel CPUs have very powerful branch prediction which might do better than PPC from the P4 era.  Unrolling is important, though, so the same instruction goes to the same place every time.  It should still work with indirect CALLs with different tables of pointers, esp. if you reuse the same table a few times in a row.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have to be *self-modifying code* at all - it can be *dynamically created code* instead, i.e. runtime-generated "trampolines".

Meaning you keep a (global) function pointer around that'll redirect to a writable/executable mapped section of memory - in which you then actively insert the function calls you wish to make.

The main difficulty with this is that `call` is IP-relative (as are most `jmp`), so that you'll have to calculate the offset between the memory location of your trampoline and the "target funcs". That as such is simple enough - but combine that with 64bit code, and you run into the relative displacement that `call` can only deal with displacements in the range of +-2GB, it becomes more complex - you'd need to call through a linkage table.

So you'd essentially create code like (/me severely UN*X biased, hence AT&T assembly, and some references to ELF-isms):

```
.Lstart_of_modifyable_section:
callq 0f
callq 1f
callq 2f
callq 3f
callq 4f
....
ret
.align 32
0:        jmpq tgt0
.align 32
1:        jmpq tgt1
.align 32
2:        jmpq tgt2
.align 32
3:        jmpq tgt3
.align 32
4:        jmpq tgt4
.align 32
...
```

This can be created at compile time (just make a writable text section), or dynamically at runtime.

You then, at runtime, patch the *jump targets*. That's similar to how the `.plt` ELF Section (PLT = procedure linkage table) works - just that there, it's the dynamic linker which patches the jmp slots, while in your case, you do that yourself.

If you go for all runtime, then table like the above is easily creatable through C/C++ even; start with a data structures like:

```
typedef struct call_tbl_entry __attribute__(("packed")) {
    uint8_t call_opcode;
    int32_t call_displacement;
};
typedef union jmp_tbl_entry_t {
    uint8_t cacheline[32];
    struct {
        uint8_t jmp_opcode[2];    // 64bit absolute jump
        uint64_t jmp_tgtaddress;
    } tbl __attribute__(("packed"));
}

struct mytbl {
    struct call_tbl_entry calltbl[NUM_CALL_SLOTS];
    uint8_t ret_opcode;
    union jmp_tbl_entry jmptbl[NUM_CALL_SLOTS];
}
```

The only critical and somewhat system-dependent thing here is the "packed" nature of this that one needs to tell the compiler about (i.e. not to pad the `call` array out), and that one should cacheline-align the jump table.

You need to make `calltbl[i].call_displacement = (int32_t)(&jmptbl[i]-&calltbl[i+1])`, initialize the empty/unused jump table with `memset(&jmptbl, 0xC3 /* RET */, sizeof(jmptbl))` and then just fill the fields with the jump opcode and target address as you need.

Comment: This is a good summary of the approach.  Viewing it as dynamically generated code possibly better.  I'm calling it self-modifying, because the goal is to prevent the processor from performing a "self-modifying-code machine clear", and because it will be running in a loop rather than generating only at start-time.  The issue with your approach is the performance the successive times through the loop:  I need predictable branches, which I think rules out indirect calls.  The call itself needs to change, and the difficulty is doing this without flushing caches and ideally without stalling.

Comment: The problem with changing the `call` themselves is that you're limited to a +- 2GB range; If that's enough you could, though, make the `call` 16-byte aligned and pad them with an 11-Byte `NOP` in-between; that way, every `call` slot is 16 Bytes and you could use `movntdq` to update the table in cache-writethrough ?

Comment: I think that I need to change the call itself, and that the call must be direct and unconditional for it to be correctly predicted the first time the code is encountered.  The purpose of this technique is to avoid the ~15 cycle branch prediction error per ~50 cycle call, and it's likely that every time will be the first time for that particular code.  Nontemporal write is not required:  it's fine if the new code gets entered into cache and displaces the old.  Rather, the goal is to prevent the entire instruction cache and pipeline from being flushed if the processor fears they are out of date.

Comment: x86-64 doesn't have a `jmp abs64` (and 32-bit doesn't have `jmp abs32`.  The only absolute direct jumps are far jumps (`jmp ptr16:32`, and you definitely don't want the CPU to spend time loading a segment descriptor, and it's not available in 64-bit mode anyway).  There's `JMP r/m64`, so you could `movabs $imm64, %rax` / `jmp *%rax`, but then you might as well have used an indirect `call *%rax`.  You could use `call *table+0` / `call *table+8` / ... for indirect calls (if that's the right AT&T syntax for loading a function-pointer from memory).  Anyway, that's data memory you can modify.

Comment: @NathanKurz: direct `call` has to be branch-predicted, too.  The mispredict cost is lower than for indirect call or jmp, but fetch can't wait until a block of code is decoded before it starts fetching from the correct address.  I think a sequence of `call 8(%rbx)`  /` call 16(%rbx)` etc. is a good bet if you're using the same block repeatedly after generating.  Data loads can mispredict, but can't SMC machine-clear.

Answer (score 3):

This is less in the scope of SMC and more into Dynamic Binary Optimization, i.e. - you don't really manipulate the code you're running (as in writing new instructions), you can just generate a different piece of code, and reroute the appropriate call in your code to jump there instead. The only modification is at the entry point, and it's only done once, so you don't need to worry too much about the overhead (it usually means flushing all the pipelines to make sure the old instruction isn't still alive anywhere in the machine, i'd guess the penalty is a few hundreds of clock cycles, depending on how loaded the CPU is. Only relevant if it's occurring repeatedly).

In the same sense, you shouldn't worry too much about doing this ahead enough of time. By the way, regarding your question - the CPU would only be able to start executing ahead as far its ROB size, which in haswell is 192 uop (not instructions, but close enough), according to this - http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/3/ , and would be able to see slightly further ahead thanks to the predictor and fetch units, so we're talking about overall of let's say a few hundreds).

Having that said, let me reiterate what was said here before - experiment, experiment experiment :)

Answer (score 2):

Very good question, but the answer is not so easy... Probably the final word will be for the experiment - common case in modern world of different architectures.

Anyway, what you want to do is not exactly self modifying code. The procedures "decode_x" will exists and will not to be modified. So, there should be no problems with the cache.

On the other hand, the memory allocated for the generated code, probably will be dynamically allocated from the heap, so, the addresses will be far enough from the executable code of the program. You can allocate new block every time you need to generate new call sequence.

How far is enough? I think that this is not so far. The distance should be probably a multiply of the cache line of the processor and this way, not so big. I have something like 64bytes (for L1). In the case of dynamically allocated memory you will have many of pages a distance.

The main problem in this approach IMO is that the code of the generated procedures will be executed only once. This way, the program will lost the main advance of the cached memory model - efficient execution of cycling code.

And at the end - the experiment does not look so hard to be made. Just write some test program in both variants and measure the performance. And if you publish these results I will read them carefully. :)

Comment: I couldn't come up with a good way to allocate a new block each time that had a unique physical address.   Do you have one?  My hope instead was to cycle through a small number of blocks and presume the oldest had been forgotten.

Comment: You can simply not free the previous allocated blocks, until the whole size become bigger than the available cache (L1 or L2?) and then cycle from already allocated blocks. As an experiment you can try to allocate them different sizes (from 1 page down) and then to compare the resulting performance.

Answer (score 2):

I found some better documentation from Intel and this seemed like the best place to put it for future reference:

```
Software should avoid writing to a code page in the same 1-KByte
subpage that is being executed or fetching code in the same 2-KByte
subpage of that is being written.
```

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf)

It's only a partial answer to the questions (test, test, test) but firmer numbers than the other sources I had found.

> 3.6.9 Mixing Code and Data.
>
> Self-modifying code works correctly, according to the Intel
>   architecture processor requirements, but incurs a significant
>   performance penalty. Avoid self-modifying code if possible. • Placing
>   writable data in the code segment might be impossible to distinguish
>   from self-modifying code. Writable data in the code segment might
>   suffer the same performance penalty as self- modifying code.
>
> Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 57. (M impact, L generality) If
>   (hopefully read-only) data must occur on the same page as code, avoid
>   placing it immediately after an indirect jump. For example, follow an
>   indirect jump with its mostly likely target, and place the data after
>   an unconditional branch. Tuning Suggestion 1. In rare cases, a
>   performance problem may be caused by executing data on a code page as
>   instructions. This is very likely to happen when execution is
>   following an indirect branch that is not resident in the trace cache.
>   If this is clearly causing a performance problem, try moving the data
>   elsewhere, or inserting an illegal opcode or a PAUSE instruction
>   immediately after the indirect branch. Note that the latter two
>   alternatives may degrade performance in some circumstances.
>
> Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 58. (H impact, L generality) Always put
>   code and data on separate pages. Avoid self-modifying code wherever
>   possible. If code is to be modified, try to do it all at once and make
>   sure the code that performs the modifications and the code being
>   modified are on separate 4-KByte pages or on separate aligned 1-KByte
>   subpages.
>
> 3.6.9.1 Self-modifying Code.
>
> Self-modifying code (SMC) that ran correctly
>   on Pentium III processors and prior implementations will run
>   correctly on subsequent implementations. SMC and cross-modifying code
>   (when multiple processors in a multiprocessor system are writing to a
>   code page) should be avoided when high performance is desired.
>
> Software should avoid writing to a code page in the same 1-KByte
>   subpage that is being executed or fetching code in the same 2-KByte
>   subpage of that is being written. In addition, sharing a page
>   containing directly or speculatively executed code with another
>   processor as a data page can trigger an 
>   ￼SMC condition that causes the entire pipeline of the machine and the
>   trace cache to be cleared. This is due to the self-modifying code
>   condition. Dynamic code need not cause the SMC condition if the code
>   written fills up a data page before that page is accessed as code.
>
> Dynamically-modified code (for example, from target fix-ups) is likely
>   to suffer from the SMC condition and should be avoided where possible.
>   Avoid the condition by introducing indirect branches and using data
>   tables on data pages (not code pages) using register-indirect calls.